# Route model binding Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I do have this Route defined in my route dir web.php, as u can see controller is expecting a wild card to be passed via url,

```
Route::get('/FeaturedPosts/{post}', 'FeaturedPostsController@index');
```

While at the controller file: I do have the index method that is dealing with the request;

```
public function show (Post $post){

return $post;
}
```

my question is why the wildcard name has to be the same as the variable name on the function at the controller ? What is the logical explanation for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one variable it would not matter how it is called, but what about this:

```
/question/{question}/answer/{answer}
```

you can call this with

```
public function show(Question $question, Answer $answer)
```

or

```
public function show(Answer $answer, Question $question)
```

Laravel is using dynamic injection so it doesn't matter where you place your variable, but it has to have a clear name to identify it.

Comment: actually it would matter ; when the var name its not the same then i get an empty json file; when the wildcard has the same name as Route model binding var then i get data on my json file. Thats why i am asking the logical explanation behind it why they have to have same name.

Comment: you can use another name, but you have to define it then in the `routeserviceprovider`. E.g. You want something like `/user/tom` instead of `/user/1`, then you have to make a new binding.